# ¿Que tan bueno es asegurar un servidor de correos de produccion con Lets Encrypt en vez de un certificado pago?

Tags: certificado-ssl, letsencrypt, dovecot

Consulta para sysadmin. Quiero preguntarles sobre el uso de certificados Letsencrypt en un servidor de Producción Ubuntu con Dovecot y Qmail. Básicamente necesito saber si hay diferencias a la hora de enviar y recibir correos y que estos lleguen en forma efectiva a destino. Entiendo que Letsencrypt, a la hora de configurar el correo en el cliente (outlook o en mi caso thunderbird), me indica que debo aceptar una excepción de seguridad como que "confio en dicho certificado letsencrypt". De ahi mi idea de que no son tan seguros y adecuados para un servidor de producción o para el uso de empleados en oficinas, ya que creo esto no sucede con un certificado externo comprado. Estoy actualizando servidores y quiero que el servicio de correos funcione en forma excelente. ¿Cual seria el standard adecuado para instalar, letsencrypt o comprado? Agradecere enormemente respuestas de sysadmin profesionales. Muchas gracias.

Comment: La naturaleza de los certificados es el evitar el repudio y generar confianza.

El repudio se da cuando un certificado no viene de una Entidad Certificadora. LetsEncrypt lo es, sólo que no sigue los mismos pasos que otras para entregarte tu certificado.
En lo puramente técnico, el certificado va a funcionar igual que cualquier otro. No hay reglas tampoco que filtren cosas de letsencrypt, que yo conozca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Letsencrypt** permite obtener un certificado solo sobre el nombre de dominio que vayas a usar para tu servidor de correo.
Es decir que el layer de transporte(TLS) se encontrará encriptado (HTTPS), pero el texto del correo en sí no se encuentra soportado y requerirá su propio certificado de encriptación.

Aparte de eso, no debería presentar ningún problema si lo configuras para la renovación automática.

El evento de excepción de seguridad generalmente se puede presentar en caso de que los certificados en la máquina destino no se encuentran actualizados.